# postMessage to iFrame with shadow dom has event.source set to event.target in latest Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, events, iframe, postmessage, shadow-dom

I have an iFrame with a shadow dom:

```
<iframe id="output-frame" src="http://localhost:8080/external/output.html" data-src="http://localhost:8080/external/output.html" style="height: 570px; width: 322px;">
    #document
        <html>...</html>
</iframe>
```

I send a post message to it:

```
postFrameOrigin: function postFrameOrigin() {
    var match = /^.*:\/\/[^\/]*/.exec(this.$el.find("#output-frame").attr("data-src"));

    return match ? match[0] : window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
},

postFrame: function postFrame(data) {
    // Send the data to the frame using postMessage
    this.$el.find("#output-frame")[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), this.postFrameOrigin());
   // Here `postMessage` is called ...
},
```

I receive it in the shadow dom:

```
bind: function bind() {
    // Handle messages coming in from the parent frame
    window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage.bind(this), false);
   // ... here `message` is received ...
},

handleMessage: function handleMessage(event) {
    var data;

    this.frameSource = event.source; // event.source contains target (falsly?)
    this.frameOrigin = event.origin;

(...)
```

In Firefox and in Chrome until version 52 I receive the source object correctly in `event.source`. From version 53 on, it contains the target object, same as in `event.target` or `event.srcElement`. (also with recent Operas, as they use Blink). Blink switched to shadow dom V1 with this version. It looks like that there is a connection.

Is this a bug? If not, how can I access the source object then?

Answer (score 1):

On my version of Chrome (v57) and Opera (v41) they are still different:

`console.assert( event.source !== event.target )` won't raise any exception.

Also, if I give distinct names to the main window and to the frame window:

```
var window.name = 'container'
...
<iframe name="frame" ...>
```

...I can watch them in the `handleMessage()` callback:

```
console.log( event.source.name )  // = container
console.log( event.target.name )  // = frame
```